# How to add a message to session when login is required in Spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a decent login system working with Spring 3 security.

If a user tries to access a secure page prior to login, he is bounced to the login page, and then upon successful login, he is redirected back to the page that he tried to access previously. This is almost exactly what I want.

**What I ALSO want is a special error message to appear on the login page explaining to the user that he has been redirected there because he has tried to access a secure area. How can I do this (without showing that error message on the login page for people who haven't previously tried to access a secure page)?**

Thanks!

P.S. I have read http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#getting-started and many posts on this site and others but have not found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using jsp? Then something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844064/303598) might be useful.
Would you like to customize your error message from Spring Security? Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1374403/303598).

Comment: Your answer probably would have worked, but I earlier solved it by pointing authentication-failure-url to a specific method that adds an error message to the session:

`<http>
<form-login login-page="/login/expire" 
...
                authentication-failure-url="/login/fail"
...
/>
...
</http>
`

and in LoginController:

`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String fail(HttpSession session) {
        flashMessageHelper.addError(MessageKey.SIGN_IN_FAILURE, session);
        return PathHelper.getRedirectToPath(linkHelper.getHome());
    }`

Answer (score 0):

On your login jsp page you can retrieve HTTP header referer (e.g. with jstl - `${header['referer']}`) which would tell you what page user tried to access before being redirected to this login page.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a error message in the login page it is something done authomaticaly by Spring. You can see how it is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844064/980472). I think that this is more about displaying login error as "Bad credentials" but take it in mind anyway.

For your case, displaying a error message related with access denied can be done just defining  the access denied page in the spring security configuration.

Usually, you can see something like this:

```
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/403.jsp">
....
</http>
```

but also you can do this and control in the login jsp if `myError` variable comes in the request:

```
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/login.jsp?myError=access-denied">
....
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the answers here provide a clean generic solution to the original problem. I do not understand OP's solution and it may be specific to his situation.

When a user clicks on a secure URL, spring redirects the user to the login page. The original request is stored in the session. And spring doesn't pass any of the parameters in the original request to the login page.

You can add something like the following to the login.jsp:

```
<%
        if((SavedRequest)session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST") != null && ((SavedRequest)session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST")).getParameterMap().get("LOGINMSG") != null){
    out.println('<%= ((SavedRequest)session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST")).getParameterMap().get("LOGINMSG")[0]%>');    
        }
        %>
```

Where LOGINMSG is the custom end user login message that you appended to the original secure URL.

I hope the spring security team would chime in and validate ( or invalidate ) this approach.

Comment: Hi Prashant.  I am trying to get this exact solution working.  My question is how to get Spring to call the java code that would put LOGINMSG on the session for the jsp to pick up.  I'm sure it's some sort of filter, but it's not an authentication filter.  How can I configure Spring to call my bit of java code that puts the extra info on the session for the login page?