# Spring security, custom login form: display custom message matching SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION

Tags: spring, error-handling, spring-security, type-mismatch

I am implementing Spring Security & I have a Custom Login form such as:

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
  <div class="errorblock">
    LOGIN ERROR<br/>
    Reason: ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}<br/>
  </div>
</c:if>

<form method="POST" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"/>">
    ...
</form>
```

So far so good, the Reason displayed is as expected (ie. `Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed` if my database is down)

I would like to be able to display a more user-friendly message, such as "Issue with database, please contact an admin"

I tried adding `typeMismatch.org.hibernate.TransactionException=Unable to connect to databse, please contact an admin` to my `messages.properties` which I already used to override Spring security auth exception, see [how to display custom error message in jsp for spring security auth exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373407/how-to-display-custom-error-message-in-jsp-for-spring-security-auth-exception)

I'm not too sure how to "call" this custom error messages.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The method in the thread you reference will only work if you want to change the message for an existing Spring message, which you can see in the message.properties file inside the security-core jar. So that won't work for what you are trying to do. You can direct to another controller on failure (see authentication-failure-url) and do whatever custom error processing you want there, then display your login form view that displays the message you built.