# Spring Security: Custom exception message from UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I am able to display the SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message ("Bad Credentials") when a user tries to log in with incorrect credentials or user is disabled for some reason.

I want to display a custom message for the case where the user is disabled, not show "Bad Credentials" instead say "You have been disabled...blah,blah...". How do I do that?

I am using UserDetailsService for providing username/password in spring security.

Comment: Have you tried an approach described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373407/how-to-display-custom-error-message-in-jsp-for-spring-security-auth-exception ?

Comment: It works, partially. I can get custom messages, however, it always returns the message configured for AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials. Even though I throw DisabledException, I get the same message as defined for badCredentials in my jsp page

Comment: Please explain what version you are using, where you are throwing the exception from and where you are displaying the message. It's probably best if you post the actual web security configuration you are using.

Comment: spring version 3.1.2. Exception is thrown from my class which implements UserDetailsService and is displayed in my login jsp page using ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set hideUserNotFoundExceptions property of [AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.html) to false. (This means this solution is dependent on the Spring Security code which might change in the future).

Here are the steps:

(1) Define a DaoAuthenticationProvider bean (if you already have one then set its hideUserNotFoundExceptions property to false). Here is Java config style:

```
    @Bean
public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider impl = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    impl.setUserDetailsService(yourUserDetailsService());
    impl.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false) ;
    return impl ;
}
```

(2) Configure authentication manager with above provider:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
<!-- other providers if any -->
</authentication-manager>
```

(3) Create an exception extending the [UsernameNotFoundException](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UsernameNotFoundException.html):

```
    public class DisabledException extends UsernameNotFoundException {

    public DisabledException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
    }

    /* other constructors */    
}
```

(4) In your UserDetailsService, throw the above exception with any message key you like:

```
    throw new DisabledException(messages.getMessage(
                        "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.disabled", "User is disabled"));
```

Here messages is `SpringSecurityMessageSource.getAccessor()`

Comment: Ritesh, thanks for your reply. The part that worked was hiding UserNotFoundException. However, now I get the message "user with name xyz not found" even if I throw my custom exception with a different message.

Comment: Jayz, the usual practice is to throw exception from UserDetailsService only when you couldn't find the user (by default BadCredentialsException will be thrown with message key AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials). If you want to indicate the disabled user then you should not throw exception and return the user with enabled flag as false (by default DisabledException will be thrown with message key AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.disabled). (Maybe this should be my answer in the first place)

Comment: Ritesh, if the application had been throwing DisabledException by default, then I wouldn't have posted this question. It does not. Even if user is disabled, it throws BadCredentialsException with message key AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials

Comment: ok. Looking at the code of AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider (3.1.0.RELEASE), there is a private class DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks that throws DisabledException if there is no exception from user details service and if user is disabled. See preAuthenticationChecks.check(user). I am not sure why it is not working; anyway, I am glad that the answer helped solve the problem.

Comment: [Not related to the question asked] Can we have open bounty for solved problems as well?

Comment: Saik0, I would refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty. Bounty has nothing to do with solved problems and neither there is requirement that OP has to search for a solution anywhere else before opening a bounty.

Comment: If you already have a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configured in Java, with an overridden configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) method and you set your userDetailService with auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService), then you can add an ObjectPostProcessor to that line in order to set the HideUserNotFoundExceptions flag: auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).addObjectPostProcessor( ...). Took me ages to find out :-(

Answer (score 0):

Create a property file in class path like loginMessage.properties

In that property file, specify

AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Username/Password entered is incorrect.

Add the following bean in your applicationContext.xml,

```
<bean id="messageSource"   
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">  
    <property name="basenames">  
        <list>
            <value>loginMessage</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In userDao, if result null

```
throw new UsernameNotFoundException("");
```

After that, u'll get message like Username/Password entered is incorrect. instead of Bad Credentials