# Spring Security redirect error message due to not being logged in

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I've tried to do some research on this, think maybe not using the right terminology to pick this up as it is a simple thing to do... I hope.

It is a spring boot web app which uses spring security with a custom authentication provider.

what I am looking for is;

if a user tries to enter a page which requires a authority (which has already been provided by the custom authentication provider) they are redirected to the login page. However I was wondering if there was a variable similar to SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION which would allow me to provide a message to the user on the jsp end which could say "sorry you have to be logged in to view this page"?

any help would be greatly appreciated!

thanks,
Jim

Comment: I hope this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373407/how-to-display-custom-error-message-in-jsp-for-spring-security-auth-exception

Comment: thanks amant and dur :)